# Openssh to IOS mail

Tags: ios, email, openssl, certificate, p12

looks like an old question, but I  couldn't make my OpenSSL certs work with IOS mail app.

I am no expert, so I would need precise step-by-step instruction.

What I have: OpenSSL, Ubuntu or windows, iPhone SE with IOS 14.x

What I would like to do and be able to share: make my own key/certificate to use sign/encrypt (mime) mails from IOS app.

I have done that for thunderbird, but I am stuck with iPhone!

Thanks for help,
Best,
--Fred

Answer (score -1):

There is no clear answer to your question on the Net as far as I know. So a nice way to have it solved once and for all... until Apple changes things again :)

Some people seem to have managed to make it work, adapting openssl config file and encapsulating data in right certificate.

Hope someone helps with this.

Best --FJ

Comment: Thanks, Fred_O, hopefully someone will spend some time to answer...